# NSFetchedResultsController not triggering willChangeContent/didChangeContent etc

Tags: ios, core-data

I use an `NSFetchedResultsController` with a stored `NSFetchRequest` on which I change the predicate.

After changing the predicate I call `performFetch` on the NSFetchedResultsController, but this does not trigger the usual `controllerWillChangeContent` ... `controllerDidChangeContent` callbacks.

So I have to `reloadData` on my table view to make it up to date.

Is this expected behaviour? Is this documented somewhere? Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's documented that those methods won't be called in response to `performFetch`, but the documentation for when they **are** called does not seem to include that case. The description of `performFetch()` indicates that

> After executing this method, you can access the receiver’s the fetched objects with the property fetchedObjects.

No mention of delegate callbacks. Meanwhile the delegate docs say that the protocol includes

> ...methods that will be called by the associated fetched results controller when the fetch results have changed.

Which doesn't specifically rule out changing to a different fetch request, but doesn't clearly include it either.

I'm pretty sure what you're seeing is normal. Changing the fetch request doesn't lead to delegate callbacks, but changing data affected by the existing fetch request does cause them.

Comment: "when the fetch results have changed" would include it in my interpretation though. The fetch results do change.

Comment: I read that as meaning when the results of the current fetch results have changed, for example because the results of the predicate have changed. Changing to a different fetch request isn't the same thing. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯